# The date like "yyyy-MM-dd" in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

How can I get the date_label to show the date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd" instead of milliseconds?
Before I stored the date as String and it worked just fine but then I changed to long because that's the way to store dates according to many "experts" on this site. I can't find a function in SQLite that does the conversion and I have tried to format DBAdapter.KEY_DATE in the String list with DateFormat without success.

```
private void fillData() {

    cursor = db.getAllWorkdays();

    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_WEEKDAY, DBAdapter.KEY_DATE , DBAdapter.KEY_WORKSTART ,
            DBAdapter.KEY_WORKEND , DBAdapter.KEY_VAKT };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView_weekday, R.id.date_label, R.id.start_label, R.id.end_label, R.id.textView4 };

    //  create an array adapter and set it to display using our row

    SimpleCursorAdapter rows = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(rows);
}
```

[This picture shows a running example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHaJv.png)

Comment: `I changed to long because that's the way to store dates according to many "experts" on this site.` Are you serious? I find myself very comfotable with using TimeStrings. You are free to use the integer format, if **you** prefer, but there's no counter-indication in using TimeStrings. Which I find more *human readable*.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to store the date as a long -- that's good.  However, SimpleCursorAdapter is too simple in this case.  You'll be better off doing a custom CursorAdapter for your ListView, and making its getView() inflate and populate the different TextView views inside the root inflated view.

When it comes time to populate the TextView that contains the date, use [formatDateTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateTime(android.content.Context,%20long,%20int)) like this:

```
long time = ...  // whatever your time is from the cursor
String date_as_string = DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, time, FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE);
```

The string will be appropriate for the user's chosen locale (they might prefer dates as YYYY-dd-MM, so let them choose).

Comment: Well, the custom CursorAdapter worked, thank you. So did the date(DateColumn / 1000, 'unixepoch') function as @CL. suggested. Should have scrolled a bit further on the SQLite page. But I REALLY can't understand why I should use long as Date storage when String is so much simpler. The number of rows not more than 50 so there is not a lot of data.

Comment: @ClasÖstman It will take more space, you'll lose precision, and you'll have to parse it every time you want to do something with that date that is not just showing the string.  Your call, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in SQLite directly.

Just use [`date(timestring, modifier, ...)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in your query.

For dates stored as an UNIX date you should use the `unixepoch` modifier.

Comment: Unfortunately the date() function takes a timestring or a Julian date number as an argument. My date is stored as an UNIX date, in milliseconds since 1970-01-01. See [link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Calculation)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) support Unix timestamps (in seconds) directly:

```
SELECT date(DateColumn / 1000, 'unixepoch') FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

- Firstly: Save dates always as long.
- Secondly: Query the long then from your Database and do: `Date date = new Date(longValue);`
- Last but not least:

  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
      sdf.format(date);`